# Unparseable date: Only on devices but not on virtual machine

Tags: android, json, parsing, date

Hi everyone i'm trying to parse a date from a Entry of RSS service but this only works on Virtual machine.

Here's my code:

```
public static com.radmas.iyc.model.rss.Response loadRssFeedExternal(String url) {
    try {
        String url2 = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=2.0&q=" + url + "&num=40&userip=" + getIPAddress();
        HttpRequest get = HttpRequest.get(url2).followRedirects(true);
        if (get.ok()) {
            String body = get.body();
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonDeserializer<Date>() {
                final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");

                @Override
                public Date deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT, final JsonDeserializationContext context) {
                    try {
                        return df.parse(json.getAsString());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    }

                }
            }).create();
            return gson.fromJson(body, com.radmas.iyc.model.rss.Response.class);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

**NOTE:** I thought it might be by the GMT Zone the VM is on GMT +0:00 and the devices on GMT +2:00 ichange that in the device but still not working.

Thank you.

**EDIT:** The String is an RSS 2.0 standar examples of RSS tha i use:

http://estaticos.marca.com/rss/portada.xml

http://futbol.as.com/rss/futbol/primera.xml

This RSS return this Date field Wed, 23 Jul 2014 12:06:04 +0200

**EDIT:** here is the trace of error:

> 07-23 12:59:34.224    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Tue, 22 Jul 2014 00:23:51 -0700" (at offset 0)
>   07-23 12:59:34.224    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:555)
>   07-23 12:59:34.224    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at com.radmas.iyc.service.RssService$1.deserialize(RssService.java:74)
>   07-23 12:59:34.224    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at com.radmas.iyc.service.RssService$1.deserialize(RssService.java:68)
>   07-23 12:59:34.224    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:58)
>   07-23 12:59:34.224    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
>   07-23 12:59:34.224    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
>   07-23 12:59:34.224    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
>   07-23 12:59:34.224    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
>   07-23 12:59:34.224    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
>   07-23 12:59:34.224    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
>   07-23 12:59:34.224    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
>   07-23 12:59:34.234    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
>   07-23 12:59:34.234    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
>   07-23 12:59:34.234    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
>   07-23 12:59:34.234    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
>   07-23 12:59:34.234    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
>   07-23 12:59:34.234    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
>   07-23 12:59:34.234    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
>   07-23 12:59:34.234    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
>   07-23 12:59:34.234    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at com.radmas.iyc.service.RssService.loadRssFeedExternal(RssService.java:82)
>   07-23 12:59:34.234    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at com.radmas.iyc.activity.news.NewsViewActivity$1.doInBackground(NewsViewActivity.java:296)
>   07-23 12:59:34.234    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at com.radmas.iyc.activity.news.NewsViewActivity$1.doInBackground(NewsViewActivity.java:288)
>   07-23 12:59:34.234    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>   07-23 12:59:34.234    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   07-23 12:59:34.234    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>   07-23 12:59:34.234    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   07-23 12:59:34.234    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   07-23 12:59:34.234    9047-9117/com.radmas.iyc.pro.canary.debug W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Comment: probably posting also the string you are failing to parse would be really helpful

Comment: Added in edit @blackbelt

Comment: do device and emulator have the same locale?

Comment: No,  like i said the Devices has GMT +2 and the emulator GMT +0 but if i change the emulator to +2 this still working however if i change device to GMT +0 doesn't work

Comment: SimpleDateFormat has a constructor with two parameters. String and Local. Provide a Locale (you should also get a warning at compile time)

Comment: @blackbelt this morning i put Locale.French and doesn´t work but now i try again with English and works fine... but only works with some.. for example now no works with this : https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=rss2

Comment: I guess that the english local is the correct one

Comment: Ok now is working magically all RSS... Thanks for the help really! Regards

Comment: Problems again when I try to open this RSS that have GMT +7 breaks again...  https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=rss2  How I can parse for all Locations?

Comment: can you get the same feed in different languages ?

Comment: No, just I use feeds random but in each individual application may configure your feeds and if in another time zone should not fail... Now it's working again... this is crazy! And the 2 zones has the shame format Wed, 23 Jul 2014 06:44:42 -0700 but diferent Time Zone